# Is there a mistake in this code example in Stroustrup's "Programming Principles and Practices" book?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I came across this code example in chapter 18 of Stroustrup's "Programming Principles and Practices with c++ 2nd ed." Book.

```
vector& vector::operator=(const vector& a)
 // make this vector a copy of a
{
 double* p = new double[a.sz]; // allocate new space
 copy(a.elem,a.elem+a.sz,elem); // copy elements
 delete[] elem; // deallocate old space
 elem = p; 
 sz = a.sz;
 return *this; 
}
```

The above example seems suspect to me. Based on my understanding, I would expect the copy function to copy into p instead of elem. Is the code right or is my fundamental understanding of this concept faulty?

Comment: You're correct, there is an error in the code.  It should be `copy(a.elem, a.elem+a.sz, p);`

Comment: See the actual/fixed code https://github.com/Chrinkus/stroustrup-ppp/blob/master/chapter18/ch18_tt_vector.cpp

Comment: Aha..thanks guys, I panicked for a while there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, and so is [JeremyFriesner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131930/jeremy-friesner)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68606596/is-there-a-mistake-in-this-code-example-in-stroustrups-programming-principles/72222589#comment121246704_68606596), which points out that it should be:

```
std::copy(a.elem, a.elem.sz, p);
```